# error while saving video file using open cv

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

program:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'VID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    out.write(frame)
    cv2.imshow('frame',gray)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/ANIKET/python projects/img_process.py", line 5, in <module>
    fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'VID')
TypeError: Required argument 'c4' (pos 4) not found
```

i m trying to save the video file.
but i m getting this error.
plz tell me what i am doing wrong

Comment: `fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/ANIKET/python projects/img_process.py", line 10, in <module>
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
cv2.error: C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:11111: error: (-215) scn == 3 || scn == 4 in function cv::cvtColor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can also use `-1` as an default argument. It had worked in my case.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
#fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',-1, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(src=frame, code=cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        out.write(gray)

        cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0):

This code addresses both your original issue (replacing `*'VID'` with `*'XVID'`) as well as your subsequent issue in the comment to your question:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'XVID')
out = cv2.VideoWriter('output.avi',fourcc, 20.0, (640,480))

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    if ret:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(src=frame, code=cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

        out.write(gray)

        cv2.imshow('frame', gray)
        if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
            break
    else:
        break

cap.release()
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Feel free to tell me if this works as you intended and point out any remaining issues!

Comment: The error can be due to incorrect spacing or other issues like     vid_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(
        osp.join(args.save_dir, args.save_name),
        cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'),
        fps = 30,
        size = (1280, 720), )

    vid_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(
        osp.join(args.save_dir, args.save_name),
        cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v'),
        args.fps,
        (args.width, args.height),
    ) I tried both and finally a spacing issue was there, this is one of the possibility